# Call stack for call trees

Tags: recursion, memory, memory-management

I have a rough idea on how recursive functions use memory creating a "call stack" but I have a doubt on that concept. Let us assume that we have a function such as the factorial() that calls himself once in every recursion step. On the other hand, there are function as Fibonacci numbers generator that calls himself two times in every step. Assuming that the total number of recursive calls for both functions is the same, would the Fibonaci function use more memory than the factorial function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, for a factorial as shown in the **stack**(in the picture below), first the value is 5, then 4, and then 3 to 1, each occupying a memory for each call of the factorial function in the stack, which depends on the height of the **recursion tree**. It should be 5 units of memory and finally, if its input was n, space complexity is in order of n. After the value of 1 is returned, the function returns and the variables disappear in the stack one by one. In fact, an ascending trend (to correct the variables in each function call) and a descending trend (for when our work is done with each function).

But for Fibonacci, first, the value is 5, the Fibonacci function is called with values ​​4 and 3, which first goes to Fib 3 (left branch). Because first it must be calculated, then go to Fib 4.In stack (I did not paint it) we have two values. Then fib of 4 becomes fib of 3 plus fib of 2. First, fib of 3 is calculated, then fib of 2. So far we have stored 3 variables in memory(5,4,3). In the same way, The numbering I did consumes as much as 5 units of memory(5,4,3,2,1 and it is the most height of the tree). So for the n as input, space complexity is the order of n. So they are equal.

picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/minp6.png)